# Create links using the ps_linklist module in PrestaShop?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

Starting with PrestaShop 1.7.5.0, the `ps_linklist` module allows admins to use the PrestaShop back office to create blocks of links. **Is there a simple way to create these links from another module?**

I've been examining the following files for clues:

- /modules/ps_linklist/ps_linklist.php
- /modules/ps_linklist/src/Model/LinkBlock.php
- /modules/ps_linklist/src/Repository/

I can do something like the following to work with PrestaShop's built-in classes:

```php
$socialTitles = Gender::getGenders();
foreach($socialTitles as $socialTitle) {
  $socialTitle->delete();
};
```

However, similar approaches don't seem to work with this module. Am I missing something, or does this module simply not implement an interface to create links from code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [Content module][1]

[1]: https://contentbox.org/ to add your links in a HTML editor the n hook it wherever you need.

It is free although they accept donations.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I know there are a number of modules that could be used. In this case, I'm wanting to work with the PrestaShop core files, and not add dependencies.